# How would I use a second input device in maya to affect controls separately to the mouse?

Tags: plugins, maya, autodesk, input-devices

Not sure if I'm in the right place but not having much luck finding anything out. What I wanted to try and do is create a plugin for autodesk software (namely maya) that allows a secondary input device to control things like the viewport camera. Basically the same concept as the 3Dconnexion space navigator but using a different input device.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Just being curious, what is the device you want to use?

Comment: First thoughts on this, certainly not the best idea but can be a good way to start and do some tests. Create a third party that analyze the inputs and sends commands to Maya through a commandPort. Also, while writing this comment, I found this [Maya API doc](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2009help/API/class_m_px_midi_input_device.html). Apparently Maya is able to do stuff with MIDI-based devices.

Comment: Wanted to experiment with something like a joystick and then try to assemble my own device. Being on a mac makes things trickier but I'm sure it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

The Maya api samples include an example of how to connect external devices. You can find an example in the maya application directory in `devkit/mocap', which includes a C++ project that uses the maya Mocap api to output continuous rotation values based on the system clock. I've seen this used to add support for joysticks and game controllers:

http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/index.html?url=files/Motion_Capture_Animation_Server_.htm,topicNumber=d30e260341

You'd want to replace the clock part, of course, with something that spits out controller values you care about.

The maya side is handled by scripts that connect incoming "mocap" data to different scene elements.  There used to be generic UI for it but nowadays you have to do it all in script:

http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/index.html?url=files/Motion_Capture_Animation_Server_.htm,topicNumber=d30e260341

I'm not too up on the current state of the art but some googling should show you how to attach device inputs to the scene

Comment: thanks, had trouble finding anything in the mountain of autodesk docs. I'm on a mac so finding anything relevant is an uphill battle.